How can i get the name of the role in ACC with the autodeskId of the role provided in Issues API
I want to get the name of a role with the autodeskId provided in Issues API with the endpoind GET projects/{projectId}/issues , i didn´t find how to get the name of the role associated to this AutodeskId.
Below i show a part of a issue.

I tried to get the roles through the users with Account Admin API, with the endpoint GET projects/{projectId}/users , but the id in role isn't AutodeskId.
Below i show the example of a roles  of a user, where the id isn't the same type that appear in issue field 'assignedTo'.


There is not an endpoint to get the project roles by ACC Admin API currently, it's a limitation as mentioned at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/field-guide/admin/#limitations.
The current suggested way is to use the Data Connector API to fetch project role data, you should be able to get the AutodeskId of the role as role_oxygen_id shown in the following picture.

